# Javascript being created in head of ASP.net every second with Ajax Timer causing issues

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a simple form that is updating a label with a timer of the current time. I noticed that when the code is ran it is adding the following to the page header every tick.

```
<script type="text/javascript">Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Sys.UI._Timer, {"enabled":true,"interval":1000,"uniqueID":"Timer1"}, null, null, $get("Timer1"));
});
</script>
```

Is this normal/OK? How do I stop this? The memory slowly creeps up and the page is bogged down after a few thousand seconds because of this. I looked online for an answer but nothing has helped.

Here is my markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm4.aspx.vb" Inherits="A2Chat.WebForm4" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="False">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000"></asp:Timer>
                    <asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server" Text="test"></asp:Label>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
Public Class WebForm4
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Label1.Text = Now()
    End Sub

End Class
```

When I inspect the page in Chrome I am seeing [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNwFr.png).

[Every second this block of code is added and I didn't actually add it but the system is adding it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIX6b.png)

FUTURE REFERENCE TO ANYONE WHO ENCOUNTERS THIS PROBLEM

Move the timer outside of the Update Panel. If you need the timer inside of an update panel then the following will get you there...

```
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    window.onload = function () {
                        setInterval(function () {
                            document.getElementById("<%=Button7.ClientID %>").click();
            }, 1000);
                    };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the timer outside of the UpdatePanel. This will stop the timer script being re-added everytime that the UpdatePanel is updated.

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm4.aspx.vb" Inherits="A2Chat.WebForm4" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000"></asp:Timer>

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="False">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server" Text="test"></asp:Label>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label1.Text = Now()
    UpdatePanel1.Update()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that but it now causes a horrible flicker. It's a place to start. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't get the flicker in my test, so I can only guess. Please see my edit with the `Handles` & `UpdatePanel1.Update()`